# Scaling in 2 axis at once

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to scale 2 axis(s) at the same time? Essentially making an object proportionally bigger.

This also applies to tighten a loop cut. In this example, the object looks tightened/constrained in only one direction but when rotated we see that it is not tightened evenly all around.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: After you press the s button push shift+axis (x or y or z)

Comment: That would work but the problem is that I am handicapped and only have the use of one hand. I use the onscreen keyboard in which the letters only momentarily press and don't stay locked while you click on something else. This also restrictions me from using the dot. and coma keys also :-(

Answer (score 13):

You can press <kbd>S</kbd>  and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>  to scale $X$ and $Y$ at the same time. Analogous to other axis.

Answer (score 4):

This problem haunted me for weeks but as in the past, I solved it before anyone needed to answer.

The trick is that I was scaling the object by clicking on the colored z-axis on the gizmo and not clicking somewhere further away.

Seems so simple now.

Comment: Clicking somewhere away will result in scale in all 3 axis, but since all your geometry is in 1 plane, it works same as scaling in 2 axis only.