# Scale Faces by Specific Value in XY Axis?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I need to scale some faces but I want to scale by an exact number I can type in. I can see the values in the top left as I scale the object but I can't click or edit the values as I am scaling the faces. I can't find any other tool settings or properties that would allow my to set the value manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the operator panel to do that:

[image]

Once you have validated the scale, you can set the values manually.

Comment: I didn't see that window pop up at the bottom, it is initially minimized. Thanks!

Comment: You can also just type any value mid operations while a scaling to input any factor

Answer (score 1):

**Keypresses.**

Following method outlined here

[Scaling in 2 axis at once](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135296/scaling-in-2-axis-at-once)

[image]

To scale selection globally in XY by 1.25

<kbd>S</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+
<kbd>Z</kbd>
<kbd>1.25</kbd>

or locally.

<kbd>S</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+
<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>
<kbd>1.25</kbd>

*Image above shows local scaling. The global XY axes appear on first <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, local when hit again.*

When using the panel can select and change multiple axes at once.

[image]